# Footer with page number and date time in all pages in PDF using Thymeleaf HTML

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf HTML along with spring boot to create PDF which can have multiple pages. The footer should consist of -

1. bottom left - "Generated On: `<timestamp>`"
2. bottom right - "Page `<count>` of `<total pages>`"

My Code :

**Part of HTML head**

```
    div.footer {
                display: block;
                text-align: left;           
                position: running(footer);
    
            }
    @page {
                size: A4 portrait;
                @bottom-right {                
                    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                }
                @bottom-left {                
                     content: element(footer);                 
    
                }
                counter-increment: page;
                counter-reset: page 1;
            }
```

**Footer**

```
    <div class="footer">
          <span th:text="${variable.generatedOn}"/>
    </div>
```

With the code above I am able to achieve partial result. The bottom right text containing the page numbers is getting printed in all pages, however the bottom left appears only in the last page.
Tried many things but not able to print both the left and right text of the footer in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched the same kind of text display in header. The issue is , you have to place the below portion after body tag.

```
 <div class="footer">
     <span th:text="${variable.generatedOn}"/>
    </div>
```

Your running elements must come first in your HTML structure. For example, if you put the footer element before the closing body tag, the running footer will only appear on the last page.